# JS dark theme not changing

Tags: javascript, toggle, darkmode

I'm trying to make light/light theme for a table  in my project,its dark by default so i'm trying to change it to light when i click on the button but when i click it changes to light but not turning back any hints ?

```
var element = document.getElementById('toggleTheme')
var attributeContent = element.getAttribute('data-layout-mode')
let toggleTheme = document.querySelector(".light-dark-mode");
let styleSheet = document.querySelector("#color-theme");

console.log(attributeContent);

if (attributeContent=="dark") {
    toggleTheme.addEventListener("click", () => {
        styleSheet.setAttribute("href", "")

        })
} else if (attributeContent=="light") {
    toggleTheme.addEventListener("click", () => {
        styleSheet.setAttribute("href", "{{ asset('css/style.css') }}")

        })
} else {
            console.log("not found")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only define what to toggle based on the initial value of the `attributeContent`.

You should better do the test, on whether it is currently dark or light, each time the toggle is clicked.

something like

```js
var element = document.getElementById('toggleTheme')
let toggleTheme = document.querySelector(".light-dark-mode");
let styleSheet = document.querySelector("#color-theme");

toggleTheme.addEventListener("click", function() {
  // read the layout mode
  var attributeContent = element.getAttribute('data-layout-mode');
  
  if (attributeContent == "dark") {
    styleSheet.setAttribute("href", "");
    // set the layout mode to the new value
    element.setAttribute('data-layout-mode', 'light');
  } else if (attributeConten == "light") {
    styleSheet.setAttribute("href", "{{ asset('css/style.css') }}");
    // set the layout mode to the new value
    element.setAttribute('data-layout-mode', 'dark');
  } else {
    console.log("not found")
  }
})
```